# Why is my tsql varbinary data getting truncated

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, binary, truncation

If I get my time zone info from the registry into SQL, I get the full TZI data structure:

```
DECLARE @TzKey nvarchar(512)
Set @TzKey = 'SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Time Zones\Pacific Standard Time'
EXEC master.dbo.xp_regread 'HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE', @TzKey, 'TZI'
```

it returns the full binary value

> '0xE001000000000000C4FFFFFF00000B0000000100020000000000000000000300000002000200000000000000'

But, if I store it in a variable like this:

```
DECLARE @TzKey nvarchar(512)
DECLARE @TZI binary(85) 
Set @TzKey = 'SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Time Zones\Pacific Standard Time'
EXEC master.dbo.xp_regread 'HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE', @TzKey, 'TZI', @TZI OUTPUT
```

Then `SELECT @TZI AS TzInfo` returns `'0xE001'`

I have tried every permutation of binary/varbinary and lengths (including MAX) that I can think of.

Any ideas?

Comment: `xp_regread` is an undocumented stored procedure - but maybe the output parameter was only ever meant for returning `smallint` values, and internally (at some point) the value is truncated to 16 bits. Doesn't matter what type of variable you give it, it's only ever going to give you 16 bits in that parameter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd do it using an `INSERT ... EXEC` and then read the value back from the table the result is inserted into:

```
DECLARE @TzKey nvarchar(512)
DECLARE @TZI binary(85) 
Set @TzKey = 'SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Time Zones\Pacific Standard Time'
declare @Results table (Value sysname,Data varbinary(300))
insert into @Results
EXEC master.dbo.xp_regread 'HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE', @TzKey, 'TZI' --, @TZI OUTPUT
select @TZI = Data from @Results
```

(Insert usual caveats about using/relying upon undocumented procedures)

Comment: @user2158889 - Really? What version are you using (initially tested on SQL Server 2012. Just re-tested on 2005)? (And I'd verified the truncation issue using your original script first, so it's not some general difference between our machines)